# Wordpress Pagination issues on custom template

Tags: wordpress

Thought this would be simple, but somehow I can't seem to figure it out. I checked the CSS to ensure nothing was set to hide display, which doesn't seem to be the case.  I have created like 10 different listings and just trying to force pagination.

On this page:
http://moemar.mailmoto.com/showcase

I simply wanted to setup custom display where I'm now showing 3 posts, which I also set under settings, but this display is forced using query parameter.

```
<?php $temp;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('category_name=Listings'.'&posts_per_page=3'.'&paged='.$paged); ?>
```

For display I'm using:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And then below the loop I have:

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous'); ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;'); ?></div>
</div>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Any ideas why my links wouldn't be showing at all?? I can see the divs just fine while inspecting, but no sign of the pagination options.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass in the maximum number of pages from your WP_Query.
Try adding this to the function calls:

```
<?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous', $wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;', $wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Added your code as is but still nothing, although I tried forcing the page through URL, and it seems to display properly when passing a page, although if it's based on the amount of posts I have, I should have at least 3 pages - http://moemar.mailmoto.com/showcase/page/2/